# Datepicker MUI X

Tags: material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

So I am trying to use Datepicker but I having a hard time changing the style of anything.
I am trying to change the border-radius and size to be small from mui sizes.

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <DatePicker
                  sx={{ marginLeft: "16px", border: 0 }}
                  className="datepicker"
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField className={"XXX"} {...params} />
                  )}
                  label="From"
                  value={value}
                  onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
                />
                <DatePicker
                  PopperProps={{
                    sx: {
                      borderRadius: 10,
                    },
                  }}
                  sx={{ marginLeft: "16px" }}
                  label="To"
                  value={value}
                  onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
                  InputProps={{ sx: { borderRadius: "200px" } }}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
```